# Data model for services quotes with MS Access

Tags: microsoft-access

I'm trying to create a simple quoting tool using MS Access. It's supposed to be a variation on the standard Orders - OrderDetails - Products type of M2M data model, however the complication is that each "product" is made up of multiple resources of various quantities. I've searched quite a bit and keep seeing the same many-to-many model, but this is kind of many-to-many-to-many.

Background: Each Quote contains line items for one or more Projects. Each Project is made up of multiple Resources (web dev, developer, project manager, designer, etc.) for a quantity of hours. If you multiply the hours time the resource rate for each resource, then add that up for the project, you'd get the cost of the project. Then all the projects added up would be the total cost of the quote.

Using an extended many-to-many relationship, I've gotten it to where I can add multiple projects and then add resources to the projects just using the nested tables. However what I'd like to be able to do is have a "catalog" of Projects where the resources and default hours are stored, then be able to add a Project to a quote. Then I need to be able to edit the hours for each resource on the quote without changing the "catalog version" of the project. As I've modeled it so far, the line item hours would be stored separately from the catalog hours.

Would I just have to use some VBA code to copy the catalog projects into a quote line item?

Here's what the structure would look like:

Quote 1234

- Project: Webpage build

  - Project manager: 10 hrs
  - Designer: 20 hrs
  - Developer: 50 hrs
- Project: Training Session

  - Trainer: 6 hrs

Quote 12345...

I have the relationships in the Access diagram, but not enough rep to post the image.

ORDERS (1-M to orders_projects)
.....................
OrdersID
Description

ORDERS_PROJECTS (1-M to orders_projects_resources, M-1 to Projects)
.......................
Orders_ProjectsID
fkOrdersID
fkProjectsID

ORDERS_PROJECTS_RESOURCES (M-1 to Resources)
..........................
ID
fkResourceID
fkOrders_ProjectsID
QtyHours

RESOURCES (1-M to Projects_Resources)
..................
ResourcesID
Title
RateHourly

PROJECTS (1-M to Projects_Resources)
.................
ID
Description

PROJECTS_RESOURCES (M-1 to Resources, M-1 to Projects)
..............................
Projects_ResourcesID
fkResourcesID
fkProjectsID
QtyHoursDefault